# Automatically wrap parameters in Options

Tags: scala

On many occasions I use parameters in form of the `Option` with `None` as default - like this:

```
def foo(bar:Option[String] = None)
```

This gets handy and allows me to easily omit `null`s. However, if I do this, I need to change every invocation of the method to

```
foo(Some("bar"))
```

instead of simply

```
foo("bar")
```

This, however, looks a bit redundant, because it is obvious, that when I specify a value it is a full option. I'm pretty sure I can try to write some implicit converters to do such wrapping for me - unfortunately, I have no idea how.

Bonus - is this a sane thing to do? Is there any other way of dealing with a problem of "nullable" parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll give you some options (pun intended).

---

Don't use an optional parameter, and instead use `Option.apply`. This is useful for when the parameter isn't necessarily optional, but you want to deal with possible `null` values being passed.

```
 def foo(bar: String): ?? = Option(bar)... // operate on the Option[String]
```

The advantage of this is that `Option.apply` automatically converts `null` to `None` for you, so there's absolutely no need to use if/else.

---

Use an overload for non-optional parameters. This is more so for when the parameter is truly optional, but gives you the convenience of passing `Option` wrapped or unwrapped. It won't be possible to pass `null` here without knowing the type first, however.

```
def foo(bar: String): ?? = foo(Option(bar))

def foo(bar: Option[String]): ?? = ???
```

Example:

```
def foo(bar: String): Option[String] = foo(Option(bar))

def foo(bar: Option[String]): Option[String] = bar.map(_ + "aaa")

scala> foo("bbb")
res7: Option[String] = Some(bbbaaa)

scala> foo(null: String) // The String ascription is necessary here.
res9: Option[String] = None

scala> val str: String = null
scala> foo(str)  // No ascription necessary, since we know the type.
res10: Option[String] = None
```

---

Implicitly convert anything to `Option`.

```
implicit def any2Opt[A](value: A): Option[A] = Option(value)
```

And keep the current definintion of

```
def foo(bar: Option[String]): ?? = ???
```

Implicitly converting to `Option`, however can result in some unexpected results, so be wary.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the desired generic implicit as

```
implicit def wrapToOption[T](x: T) = Option[T](x)
```

Then you can do

```
def foo(bar: Option[String] = None) = println(bar)
foo("bar") //> Some(bar)
foo()      //> None

def fooBar(bar: Option[Int] = None) = println(bar)
fooBar(2) //> Some(2)
```

About it being sane thing to do, I will say no(personal opinion). Implicits are  notoriously hard to debug. A logic gone wrong in the implicits can make your life hell.

Also, each new addition to the team will have to taught about all these "magics" happening behind the scenes.

Comment: WoW! It works! However, you are right about those "magic" I still have to add this implicit (or import) in every file I use.

Comment: @M4ks if you're concerned about the "magic", see my answer bellow that offer a way to mitigate that.

Comment: I think the @m-z answers is a bit better as it presents the non-magic solution, sorry for "unaccepting"

Answer (score 1):

It is a perfectly reasonable approach to set the type of your parameters to `Option[_]`, if they really can be optional. However, I do not recommend using implicits to convert directly to `Option[_]`.

You can make the syntax a little easier on the eye by including Scalaz and using `some`:

```
foo("hello".some)
```

If you don't want to bring in Scalaz just for that it's very easy to write your own implicit to do so.  This implicit is better because you explicitly call the `some` method to "trigger" the implicit, as opposed to a "magical" conversion.

Another alternative, if you often call a function with parameters set to `Some[_]` is to overload it (again, I'm not a fan of overloading either):

```
def foo(x: Option[String] = None, y: Option[Int] = None, z: Option[String] = None) { /* do stuff */ }

def foo(x: String, y: Int, z: Option[String] = None) = foo(x.some, y.some, z)
```

On a final note, I don't think there is anything wrong with wrapping your arguments in `Some` if the function clearly defines them as optional.  I wouldn't worry to much about this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you can define an implicit converter as :

```
   implicit def conv(str: String): Option[String] = {
      if (str == null) None else Some(str)
    }

    def foo(bar: Option[String] = None) = {
      bar
    }
```

Output:

```
scala> foo("xyz")
res55: Option[String] = Some(xyz)
scala> foo()
res1: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Option(null) is equal to None.

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly converting everything to an `Option` is a dangerous game that I would avoid!  You might prefer simply having some method overloads:

```
object Foos {
    private def foo(bar: Option[String]): Unit = println(bar.getOrElse("foobar"))
    def foo(bar: String): Unit = foo(Some(bar))
    def foo(): Unit = foo(None)
}
```

And then you can do:

```
Foos.foo("barfoo") //prints "barfoo"
Foos.foo() //prints "foobar"
```

While still only really implementing the method once.  Furthermore, you can hide the `Option` overload this way.